# Commands on hosts when docker is up?

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

Is there a possibility to run some commands on host when my `docker-compose up` is running?

In my case I am building a set of containers for 2 projects and some of containers are facilitating frameworks tools or phing for migrations and other tasks. I'd like to prepare a set of aliases to be able to run some common tasks from host level instead of running `docker-compose exec web command` just write `drun command` or something like that.

For now I came up with a `build.sh` where I would define a set of such aliases and then run `docker-compose up` but is there easier way for that?

Comment: Don’t think there is a better solution on the base principle. I used two things in the past : alias in bashrc or command in a makefile. I would go for the makefile in your case.

Comment: You could use [`Stack`](https://github.com/flexbox-it/stack), a python tool I wrote exactly for this purpose. There's a possibility to set the commands to be run after you do `stack up`, which in fact runs `docker-compose up -d` and executes a set of instructions afterwards.